# Send mail by getting recipient mail from Excel

Tags: python, excel

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

"""
    This script is designed to send emails to multi recepients from local and  other SMTP servers.
    Any kind of documents can be attached with the email to be sent.

    To send the email from the local SMTP server it is assumed that an email client is already
    configured on your local system (postfix, sendmail etc.).

    To send the email from gmail server it is necessary to allow "less secure apps"
     (https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps) in your Google account
"""


    for row in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=2, values_only=True):
        company = row[0]
        stmt = row[1]
        areawise = row[2]
        email_addresses = row[3]
        if __name__ == "__main__":
            user = 'xyz@gmail.com'  # Email userID
        password = 'secret'  # Email password
        from_addr = 'abc@gmail.com'
        recipients_addr = email_addresses
        subject = company
        body = stmt
        file_path = areawise
        send_email(user, password, from_addr, recipients_addr, subject, body, file_path)
```

Above code is executed successfully but mail not sent.

Answer (score 0):

> To help keep your account secure, from May 30, 2022, ​​Google no longer supports the use of third-party apps or devices which ask you to sign in to your Google Account using only your username and password.

https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en

Comment: if __name__ == "__main__":
    user = 'xyz@gmail.com'  # Email userID
    password = 'secret'  # Email password
    from_addr = 'xyz@gmail.com'
    # CHANGE 2

    recipients_addr = ['recipients2@gmail.com', 'recipients1@gmail.com',]
    subject = 'AREAWISE'
    body = 'Please find the attachaments of areawise/stament for the month of APRIL 2023 - ES'
    # CHANGE 1
    file_path = ['A_STMT.pdf','A_AREAWISE.pdf']
    send_email(user, password, from_addr, recipients_addr, subject, body, file_path)       above code works fine

Comment: Please add to your question the send_email() code.